# Why doesn't Israel ask Palestinians in Gaza Strip to move to the Negev to a camp managed by UNHCR?

Tags: israel, palestine, refugees, gaza, 2023-israel-hamas-war

Israel has been urging Palestinians to move south and leave Gaza city since the start of the war, with their war on Hamas fighters, a high number of civilians are falling casualties.

Israel could have avoided this high number of civilian casualties and the world wide condemnation and protests against its operation if it had first relocated all civilians out of the Gaza Strip to Negev and then attacked an empty Gaza without any civilians, this would have significantly reduced civilian casualties, and faced less objection from the world community.

With their next planned operation in the south of Gaza Strip and Egypt's refusal to take in that many refugees, Israel can avoid a likely even higher number of casualties by relocating them to the Negev in a UNHCR camp. So, why don't they just do that?

UNHCR : [Do not conflate refugees with terrorists](https://www.unhcr.org/cy/wp-content/uploads/sites/41/2015/12/JointStatementUNHCR-Ombudswoman_Dec2015.pdf)

Egyptian president Al-Sisi suggested this previously:
[Sisi suggests that Israel move Gazans to Negev, not Sinai](https://www.naharnet.com/stories/en/301042-sisi-suggests-that-israel-move-gazans-to-negev-not-sinai)

And the suggestion [was](https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/blogs/menasource/humanitarian-corridor-israeli-negev-gaza-hamas/) echoed by some US academics:

> The Israeli Negev is comparatively lightly populated and could temporarily accommodate women and children fleeing Gaza by providing a humanitarian corridor to vacant land in the south. We are not alone in this suggestion. Egypt’s President Sisi has floated the same idea. The situation in Gaza has become so dire that it needs to be considered. Israel would control their exit from the strip, vetting each one to ensure that no woman, child, nor elderly Gazan could possibly pose a threat. The international community could immediately provide the assistance—tents, food, fuel, medical supplies, and care—required to address the needs of hundreds of thousands of refugees.

Comment: Re: *"and then attacked an empty Gaza without any civilians"*: (a) It would be a very stupid terrorist who would stay behind in an otherwise empty Gaza, where he would instantly become the target of Israeli army, and (b) it would be very stupid of Israel to attack an empty space. I wouldn't attack empty spaces, and I doubt that a professional army would do that either. :)

Comment: But that is what is currently happening in Gaza city, it is empty of civilians.

Comment: As of today, here is a photo of civilians: "Palestinians inspect damaged buildings following the Israeli counter-strikes at Beach refugee camp in Gaza City.", [1](https://www.axios.com/2023/11/22/israel-hamas-hostage-deal-timeline-palestinian-prisoners). And as of today, also: "Only two small hospitals to the north of Wadi Gaza (hereafter: the north), one in Gaza city and another in Beit Lahiya, are estimated to be partially operational and able to admit patients" [2](https://imemc.org/article/day-46-of-israeli-assault-on-gaza-4-doctors-among-178-palestinians-killed/)

Comment: Ok, but there aren't 100's of 1000's there as they used to be, the majority moved south. Argument still stands. Get the same number who moved south into Israel instead to reduce civilian casualties. If Israel go ahead with invading the south, there will be almost double the concentration, will they invade with that many people in?

Comment: I addressed this in my [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/82813/28554) below.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly because they (Israelis) feel a lot safer with the Gaza population behind a wall of semi-automated gun turrets, tunnel barriers/detectors, etc. In theory, they could build that in the Negev too, but what would be the point when they already have that around Gaza? To say nothing of the complexities of moving the population farther away.

And what I mean by the latter includes: a lot of people in Israel don't feel confident in distinguishing between the Gaza civilians and Hamas, particularly when the latter are unarmed. Yes, moving them elsewhere through a "filter" could mean no/few weapons reach the destination. But that would require a lot of inspection effort, close contact which has the risk of suicide bombers acting etc.

I don't know if any Israeli officials have bothered to comment on the Negev proposal, but their preferred solution [appears](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67518819) to be for the Gaza civilians to go al-Mawasi, inside Gaza, by the sea.

> "It's going to be dire. But they'll live," says Lt Col Richard Hecht, an IDF spokesman.
>
> For Israel, it's a matter of military necessity. Just as Hamas was embedded in Gaza City, it says, so the group's fighters and infrastructure exist in Khan Yunis and Rafah. Removing the civilian population ahead of an assault, Israelis argue, is the humane way to approach the job of defeating Hamas.
>
> "People in Israel don't like the situation where people in Gaza are somewhere in al-Mawasi, under the rain of winter, which is coming," says retired Maj Gen Yaacov Amidror, a former Israeli national security adviser. "But what is the alternative? If someone has an idea how to destroy Hamas without it, please tell us."

As also noted in that piece, the UN agencies aren't excited about that proposal though, owing to what they say is lack of infrastructure in that al-Mawasi area.

Comment: But we are talking about civilians here. The wall, semi-automated gun turrets, tunnel barriers/detectors, etc are mainly against Hamas. Israel could have created a refugee area under UNHCR just like any refugee camps around the world.

Comment: @Mocas A lot of people in Israel don't feel confident in distinguishing between the civilians and Hamas, particularly when the latter are unarmed. Yes, moving them elsewhere through a "filter" could mean no/few weapons reach the destination. But that would require a lot of inspection effort, close contact which has the risk of suicide bombers acting etc.

Comment: I honestly doubt that a camp managed by UNHCR would have any terrorist attacks. For some reason I can't do [at]Fizz

Comment: @Mocas what evidence do you have to back up that feeling?

Comment: @JoeW https://www.unhcr.org/cy/wp-content/uploads/sites/41/2015/12/JointStatementUNHCR-Ombudswoman_Dec2015.pdf

Comment: @Mocas that is a statement that refugees are not terrorists not a statement saying that the camps are protected from terrorists doing things when they sneak into a camp

Comment: @JoeW From the statement *"Conflating refugees with terrorists is irrational.
It is not logical. Worse still, it is dangerous"*, which is exactly what you are doing now.

Comment: @Mocas And the concern is that terrorists will sneak into the groups that are moving out of gaza for saftey. I am not saying that refugees are terrorists rather that they would attempt to move with them.

Comment: @JoeW And I answered this in the comments under the question, if they do move with them, they will have no use to Hamas. It is better for Hamas if they stay in Gaza to fight Israel rather than thrown their weapons and sneak out. If they do sneak out, even better, less Hamas fighters to fight in Gaza and easier operation.

Comment: @Mocas you shouldn’t answer important questions in the comments but that still doesn’t stop them from attempting to move with the civilians and making attacks on Israel again

Comment: @JoeW What am I missing here? I am just repeating myself. I didn't say they won't move, if they do move it is even better for Israel. Read above.

Comment: @Mocas You asked why they didn't move the civilians to a camp and it was pointed out that won't stop Hamas from moving with it as well and still performing attacks with that as a base.

Comment: @Mocas: and I haven't DV your Q. Perhaps you could add [to it] that it was apparently seriously suggested, e.g. by Egypt. So it would appear less than just your random idea.

Comment: @Mocas you can't ping Fizz with the @ sign because you're posting the comment on an answer posted by Fizz, and therefore Fizz will be notified of your comment even without an explicit @ mention.  There's some logic that deletes such redundant @ mentions from comments.

Comment: @Mocas I doubt that Israel has confidence that the UNHCR would manage camps in a way that would avoid terror attacks, given it's [strong anti-Israel bias](https://www.jpost.com/bds-threat/article-712721).

Answer (score -2):

**TL;DR: If even Egypt does not want the civilians from Gaza, why would Israel?**

Not even Egypt, a Gaza neighbor, and an Arab state widely viewed as an ally to the Palestinian Arabs, wants Gaza civilians:

> A chorus of Egyptian officials, media personalities, and religious authorities have stated over the past two days — with almost exactly the same wording — that Egypt will not tolerate Israel pushing Palestinians into Egypt at the expense of “Egyptian sovereignty.”

*[Why does Egypt fear evacuating Gaza? - Responsible Statecraft](https://responsiblestatecraft.org/egypt-gaza-israel/)*

Given the long history of Gaza-based terrorist attacks on the Israeli civilians, it is completely understandable that Israel has even *less* incentive than Egypt to accept refugees from Gaza.

And Egypt is the country that perhaps knows best the issues associated with governing the population of Gaza - after all, ["Egypt ... kept it under military rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupation_of_the_Gaza_Strip_by_the_United_Arab_Republic) until 1967. Here is how *that* looked like:

> Because the Egyptian government restricted movement to and from the Gaza Strip, its inhabitants could not look elsewhere for gainful employment. In 1955, one observer (a member of the United Nations Secretariat) noted that "For all practical purposes it would be true to say that for the last six years in Gaza over 300,000 poverty stricken people have been physically confined to an area the size of a large city park."

*[Occupation of the Gaza Strip by the United Arab Republic - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupation_of_the_Gaza_Strip_by_the_United_Arab_Republic)*

And Egypt learned its history lessons well, and takes seriously the task of keeping Gazan civilians out of Egypt:

> Israel ... also signed a peace treaty with Egypt at Camp David — a pact negotiated by U.S. President Jimmy Carter. Egyptian President Abdel Fattah el-Sissi referenced this 40-year old treaty Wednesday when he declined to permit Palestinian refugees from Gaza into Egypt, saying the potential entrance of militants into Egypt would threaten longstanding peace between Israel and Egypt.
> ...
> Israel and Egypt imposed a crippling blockade on the territory, monitoring the flow of goods and people in and out. For nearly two decades, the closure has crippled the local economy, sent unemployment skyrocketing, and emboldened militancy in the region, which is one of the most densely populated places on the planet.

*[Gaza has long been a powder keg. Here's a look at the history of the embattled region | AP News](https://apnews.com/article/gaza-history-israel-palestinians-hamas-egypt-688d202c53c0cc72bf2242dccb47fcd5)*

> Egypt controls Gaza Strip's southern border, under an agreement between it and Israel. Neither Israel or Egypt permits free travel from Gaza as both borders are heavily militarily fortified. "Egypt maintains a strict blockade on Gaza in order to isolate Hamas from Islamist insurgents in the Sinai."

*[Gaza Strip - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza_Strip)*

An interesting historical fact is that this is *not* the first time Egypt rejected responsibility over civilians from Gaza:

> With the defeat of the Central Powers in World War I and the subsequent partition of the Ottoman Empire, the British deferred the governance of the Gaza Strip area to Egypt (which declined the responsibility).

*[Gaza Strip - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza_Strip)*

Comment: Egypt has no obligation to accept Gazans, they are residents of Gaza, an Israeli occupied territory under international law, that makes Israel responsible for them not Egypt.

Comment: Israel did not occupy Gaza before the [October 7, 2023 Hamas attack on Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Hamas_attack_on_Israel). Israel is not responsible for Gaza under international law. Egypt, then Israel did occupy Gaza, but that was until 2005. Since then, Gazans ruled themselves, which resulted in the democratic election of the terrorist group Hamas, which ruled Gaza from 2007 until now. See: [Gaza Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza_Strip). To say that someone else is responsible for Gaza is to intentionally humiliate the Palestinians and deprive them of agency.

Comment: Gaza is an Israeli occupied territory as per International Committee of the Red Cross (ICRC), the United Nations Independent International Commission of Inquiry on the Occupied Palestinian Territory, UN General Assembly (UNGA), European Union (EU), African Union, International Criminal Court (ICC) (both Pre-Trial Chamber I and the Office of the Prosecutor), Amnesty International, and Human Rights Watch—as well as international legal experts and other organizations, https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/blogs/menasource/gaza-israel-occupied-international-law/

Comment: Using the common sense, since Israel did not have an occupying army in Gaza before the October 7 terrorist attack of Hamas, and did not rule Gaza (Hamas did), many people would consider the Gazans to be ruling themselves. To say that they do not is nonsense. It is not Israel who elected Hamas, it is the Gazans that did it. And it does seem like no one wnats to let Gazans into their country - have you ever wondered why? :)

Comment: You are calling what all these international organisations are saying nonsense? Well, your "common sense" must be superior then. The United Nations, international human rights organisations, and the majority of governments and legal commentators still consider the territory to be occupied by Israel despite the 2005 Israeli disengagement from Gaza.

Comment: After its disengagement in 2005, Israel maintains direct external control over Gaza and indirect control over life within Gaza.
Israel controls Gaza's air and maritime space and six of Gaza's seven land crossings.
Israel reserves the right to enter Gaza at will with its military and maintains a no-go buffer zone within the Gaza territory.
Gaza is dependent on Israel for its water, electricity, telecommunications, and other utilities

Comment: @Mocas, we should acknowledge that on October 7 Hamas did at will enter the Israel territory, hence we conclude, that Hamas indeed occupies its non-sovereign territory [per Wikipedia]. Therefore, Palestinians occupy Israel. You should continue execute this kind of logic consistently and not only in favor of your own agenda.

Comment: @dEmigOd I don't really understand what you wrote. Anyway, what happened on October 7 doesn't change the fact and the status of the Israel's Occupation of Gaza.

Comment: Why does it matter what Israel wants? You don't get to kill thousands of people because you "don't want them"

Comment: @user253751 This is irrelevant to the OP's Q. And note that I do not discuss "killing" of "thousands of people" in my A. Feel free to raise this topic in a separate Q.